# Extract string between the last but one white space and the last white space in r

Tags: regex, r

I want to pick up the word between the last but one white space and the last white space in r. For example, for the string `'Albert Avenue Ngahio 6088'` the output in r I want is

```
[1] "Ngahio"
```

For the string `'Barie Road Johnvile 6051'`, I want to pick up

```
[1] "Johnvile"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ss = 'Albert Avenue Ngahio 6088'
uu = unlist(strsplit(ss, ' '))
uu
[1] "Albert" "Avenue" "Ngahio" "6088"  

uu[length(uu)-1]
[1] "Ngahio"
```

A function can be created:

```
myfn = function(ss){
 uu = unlist(strsplit(ss, ' '))
 uu[length(uu)-1]
}

myfn("Albert Avenue Ngahio 6088")
[1] "Ngahio"

myfn('Barie Road Johnvile 6051')
[1] "Johnvile"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want `sapply` here.  It's very simple with `sapply` and `strsplit`

```
> s <- c("Albert Avenue Ngahio 6088", "Barie Road Johnvile 6051")
> sapply(strsplit(s, "\\s+"), `[`, 3)
# [1] "Ngahio"   "Johnvile"
```

Or, a more general method to find the element second from the end is

```
> sapply(strsplit(s, "\\s+"), tail, 2)[1,]
# [1] "Ngahio"   "Johnvile"
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do. You can also use `"\\s+"` for the split in strsplit if you want to cover any combination of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Through `sub`,

```
> f <- "Albert Avenue Ngahio 6088"
> sub("^.*?(\\S+)\\s*\\S+$", "\\1", f, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Ngahio"
> sub("^.*?(\\S+)\\s*\\S+$", "\\1", "Barie Road Johnvile 6051", perl=TRUE)
[1] "Johnvile"
```

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `.*?` Matches any character zero or more times. `?` quantifier after `*` force the regex engine to do a shortest possible match.
- `(\S+)` One or more non-space characters are captured and it was stored into a group. You could refer the captured later by using it's index number.
- `\s*` Matches Zero or more space characters.
- `\S+$` Matches one or more non-space character which must be the last string because of the following line end anchor `$`.